# Rest API w with SlimPhp take too much time

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I developed a REST API using php and slim, I am trying to optimize it , for a simple empty request with slim I have 56requests per second , and if I don't use slim I have 259r/s .

What Should I do to reach 259r/s with Slim

-- Index.php

```
use \Slim\App;

$container=include('Config/Container.php');
$app = new App($container);
$app->get('/metro',function(){
echo "metro";
});
```

-- container.php

```
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'mode'=>'developpement',
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
    ]
];
```

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
php_flag display_errors 1
```

Comment: Where is your code? How are we supposed to help? What are these statistics?

Comment: @nerdlyist It's an empty request , mean an empty code . . I created a client  python to request many time the server to get those statistics

Comment: What does your index and htacess look like?

Comment: @nerdlyist I updated it with code

Comment: That setup wouldn't seem to impede anything. Are your response times slower on a slim route vs the other way?

Comment: Actually wouldn't you want `$app = new App($container);` to be your `$config` in `config.php`?

Comment: @nerdlyist exactly , the response is 5 time slower with Slim Vs without it .  The container.php contains verification too that's why I put it in other file

Comment: So what is this verification and is that happening on your comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All frameworks are by definition slower than no-code as there's more going on.

i.e.

```
<?php
echo 'metro';
```

is going to be much faster than a Slim application with this code:

```
use \Slim\App;

$config = include 'Config/Container.php';
$app = new App($config);
$app->get('/metro', function($request, $response){
    return $response->write("metro");
});

$app->run();
```

This is because the Slim application is doing a lot more to enable it to respond to different URLs (routing) and handle error situations. That is the first block of code will not send back a 404 if you go to the `/foo` URL.

To compare, you need to make the "non-framework" version have the same functionality as the Slim version. The performance difference will be much smaller.